# Volley StringRequest passing an integer

Tags: kotlin, android-volley

I'm trying to call an API, and I have to pass an Integer as a paramether. The problem is that paramether must be a String. How can I get the value as an Integer?

The issue is in params.put

```
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, Response.Listener<String>{ s ->
        try {
            val array = JSONArray(s)
            for (i in 0..array.length() - 1) {
                val objectComment = array.getJSONObject(i)
                val comment= Comment(
                    objectComment.getInt("userId"),
                    objectComment.getInt("id"),
                    objectComment.getString("title"),
                    objectComment.getString("body"))
                    list.add(comment)
            }
        }catch (e: JSONException){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }, Response.ErrorListener { error: VolleyError? -> Log.e("error", error.toString())  }){
        override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
            val params = HashMap<String, String>()
            params.put("postId", 2)
            return params
        }
    }
```

Comment: use (number).toString() i.e. 2.toString() or "$VarName" or  ""+2 in kotlin all will work but use the first one it the standard one

Comment: still not working. I'm trying to call this api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments and using this as a param: postId passing 2 as a value, but is not giving me the correct result

Comment: {"userId";1, "id":1,"title":"title","body":"bodyyyy"} the above link don't have this json structure in the array of json.please check u will get body and id only if request got sucess also, in params postId is int type only on the above link so no need to convert the 2 into string atall

Comment: var postid=2; val url="jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=$postId" and use this you will get the filter result of postId=2 only, not the full, as you want and no need to pass the param as u are passing. check with server team as how they want the param in body in queryparameter or in header then only u pass the param to the volley.